# Usecontext typing в typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, useeffect

Файл с типизацией:

```
//types.tsx

export interface IAsteroid {
    close_approach_data: Array<IcloseApproachData>,
    estimated_diameter: {
        meters: {
          estimated_diameter_min: number,
          estimated_diameter_max: number,
        },
    },
    id: string,
    is_potentially_hazardous_asteroid: boolean,
    name: string
}



export interface UserContextType {
  unit: string
  setUnit: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<string>>
  asteroids: IAsteroid[]
  setAsteroids: React.Dispatch<React.SetState/Action<IAsteroid[]>>
};
```

```
//AppContext.tsx

"use client"
import React, { createContext, useState, useContext, ReactNode } from 'react';
import {IAsteroid} from './types/types'
import {UserContextType} from './types/types'


const AppContext = createContext<UserContextType | null>(null);

export const AppProvider = ({children}: {children: ReactNode }) => {

    const [unit, setUnit] = useState<string>('lunar')
    const [asteroids, setAsteroids] = useState<IAsteroid[] | []>([])

    const value = {
     asteroids,
     setAsteroids,
     unit, 
     setUnit
    };
 
    return (
    <AppContext.Provider value={value}>
        {children}
    </AppContext.Provider>
    )
}
 

 export const useAppContext = ()=> useContext(AppContext)
```

```
//Approaches/index.tsx

'use client'

import { useAppContext } from '../../AppContext'
import styles from './approaches.module.css'

export interface props {
  children: React.ReactNode; }


// Компонент вывода блока на главной странице: фильтра и всех астероидов (children)
export default function Approaches({children}: props) {

    const {unit, setUnit } = useAppContext()


    const handleClick = (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLSpanElement>) => {
      setUnit((e.target as HTMLSpanElement).getAttribute("data-unit"))
    }


  return (
    <section className={styles.asteroid}>
        <h3 className={styles.nearbyAsteroids}>Ближайшие подлёты астероидов</h3>
        <div className={styles.filter}>
          <span onClick={handleClick} data-unit='kilometers' className={`${styles.filter__item} ${unit === 'kilometers' ? styles.active : ''}`}>в километрах</span>
          <span> | </span>
          <span onClick={handleClick} data-unit='lunar' className={`${styles.filter__item} ${unit === 'lunar' ? styles.active : ''}`} >в лунных орбитах</span>
        </div>
        {children}
    </section>
  )
}
```

Ошибка здесь:

```
const {unit, setUnit } = useAppContext()
```

> Свойство "unit" не существует в типе "UserContextType | null".ts(2339)
>
> const unit: any

> Свойство "setUnit" не существует в типе "UserContextType | null".ts(2339)
>
> const setUnit: any

Подскажите пожалуйста как убрать эту ошибку, не могу понять откуда и почему эта ошибка возникает.

Comment: Скорее всего из-за того, что у Вас объект или null, и если в объекте свойство есть, то null не удовлетворяет этому условию